# Regex to match the filename of a path

Tags: .net, regex

Considering a Windows-style path like:

```
c:\foo bar\a\b\c\xtesty
```

What is a regex that validates that the filename (*xtesty* in the example above) contains the word "*test*"?

Note: this is a regex question, using file system methods like System.IO in .net is not an option;

Note2: As stribizhev points there is some variation is path separators in different cultures and OSes. This question is for en-us and Windows only, so the separator is /

Context: I am offering users the possibility of specifying a regex as a setting to match some paths. By default this regex should be - any filename (not the entire path!) that contains the word "test"

Comment: You mean this `[^\/]*$`

Comment: No, it is not a regex task, almost all programming languages can handle that easily without a regex. What are you using for this task?

Comment: split on \ and get the last index.

Comment: @Avinash - it needs to be a regex and the file name should contain 'test'

Comment: @stribizhev - I added more context to the question, but thank you for your suggestion anyway

Comment: @BogdanGavril-MSFT: What about Japanese/Chinese OSes? Well, not that easy, actually. But why not trying [`[^\\¥]*test[^\\¥]*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5c%5c%c2%a5%5d*test%5b%5e%5c%5c%c2%a5%5d*%24&i=c%3a%5cfoo+bar+test%5ca%5cb%5cc%5cxtesty).

Comment: @stribizhev - very good point about the non-en OSes. I'll add a note to the question. If you add an answer with your suggestion I'll vote it. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this regex:

```
[^\\¥]*test[^\\¥]*$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5C%5C%C2%A5%5D*test%5B%5E%5C%5C%C2%A5%5D*%24&i=c%3A%5Cfoo%20bar%20test%5Ca%5Cb%5Cc%5Cxtesty)

A bit faster one with atomic groups (don't know why .NET regex engine still does not support possessive quantifiers :():

```
(?>[^\\¥]*test)(?>[^\\¥]*$)
```

The point is that there are other than `\` path separators, like e.g. YEN SIGN that is used in Japanese OS. Also, if you plan to let variables in, they must be escaped (just in case, to play it safe, with `Regex.Escape`).

If you plan to only support English-like cultures, remove the `¥` from the regex.